# How do I dual boot Windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04.2?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

I doing a clean install so I will be removing everything from my HDD, I have created bootable usb for both the OS, I am currently running windows 8.1 only but want to dual boot both the above stated OS's also I will not be upgrading(i.e keeping my old data) from win 8.1, should I wipe everything first and then install or something else? Also If I were to wipe everything is it recommended that I install Ubuntu first or win 10?Also I will be doing the above on my laptop having Intel Pentium and 2 gigs of ram, is this recommended?

P.S - I am new to the forum and this is my first question so please forgive me if I have done anything wrong.

Comment: whatever you did first it does not matter. You can install both win 10 and ubuntu14.04. Did you dual boot before ?

Comment: No, I have not dual booted before, I want to know if it is easier to install win 10 first and then ubuntu or the other way around?

Comment: I recommend you do more research. There are lots of instructions on dual booting stuff just a google away

Comment: possible duplicate of [In setting up dual Boot with Windows and Ubuntu, which OS do I install first?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152991/in-setting-up-dual-boot-with-windows-and-ubuntu-which-os-do-i-install-first) You already have Windows 8.1 installed first, so you can easily upgrade it to Windows 10 without losing your old data and install Ubuntu afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're doing a clean install of Windows 10, the process should be very similar to e.g. dual booting Windows 8.1.

I [briefly read over this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/installation), and believe you can use it for reference.

The most important points are the following:

- You should install Windows before Ubuntu (because this is better supported)
- To prevent filesystem corruption on the Windows side, you need to [configure Windows a bit before installing Ubuntu](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/windows)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The currently best option for dual (or tripple/quad, etc.) booting is in my opinon [clover](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/), which is also extensively used by the hackintosh community, but also works perfectly as a bootloader for Windows and Linux. 
As @vindvaki already pointed out, installing Windows before anything else is also crucial here (as also [outlined in a win10-related post in the clover forum](http://sourceforge.net/p/cloverefiboot/discussion/1726372/thread/08da9474/)).

There is an existing guide which i can recommend ([[Guide]Triple Boot Windows, Linux and Mavericks on Acer Aspire 5755G using Clover](http://www.tonymacx86.com/mavericks-laptop-support/135154-guide-triple-boot-windows-linux-mavericks-acer-aspire-5755g-using-clover.html)) , for installing Clover from Windows there is [BootDiskUtility](http://cvad-mac.narod.ru/index/0-5). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you install Ubuntu first, then windows, windows boot loader can't detect Ubuntu partitions and you don't be able to boot Ubuntu, then you must isntall Grub boot loader from Ubuntu installation media. So i think it's better to install Windows 10 first then Ubuntu, and in Ubuntu boot loader will be displayed Ubuntu and Windows. On my laptop there is windows 10 and Ubuntu, but grub say's that is Windows 8, but everything work's perfect.

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)