# Installing Ubuntu 19 and Windows 10 Professional on a Lenovo IdeaPad Y510P

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

I'm planning to dual boot Ubuntu 19 and Windows 10 prof. on a Lenovo IdeaPad Y510P which comes with a 24 GB SSD and a 1 TB HDD so I suspect the partition scheme is a bit tricky. I wish to install both OS on the SSD drive and install programs and data on the 1 TB HDD.

1. What's the recommended partition scheme for each drive?
2. Which OS should I install first?
3. How do I deal with the UEFI when installing the OS? Should I disable it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Advantages of separate /home partition on HDD + SSD setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258259/advantages-of-separate-home-partition-on-hdd-ssd-setup) and [In setting up dual Boot with Windows and Ubuntu, which OS do I install first?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152991/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm planning something similar to this. So I've already made my homework and share it with you:

1. Windows needs at least 60 GB I recommend to give each OS 115 GB so you have 10 GB unused space on your SSD, to sustain durability. Furthermore, Windows creates the necessary Partitions and the Ubuntu-Installation afterward suggests to Install Ubuntu alongside Windows and also creates the necessary Partitions. For your 1TB-Drive: It must have either be NTFS or FAT32 formated. And more importantly, you mustn't tell Windows to create a dynamic Disk, It has to be a Basic Disk if you want, that Ubuntu can access it.
2. It's much easier to install Windows on your entire Disk first and afterward install Ubuntu, so Ubuntu can just shrink the Windows Partitions.
3. You don't have to disable it, because of the fact, that the Ubuntu ISO is capable of UEFI-Systems. As far as I'm informed, you can't enable UEFI afterward, without possibly break your System.

Comment: It sounds like my best choice would be to install Ubuntu on the HDD drive.  Ideally, I could install a bigger SSD drive, but I'm trying to make the current hardware configuration work.  I currently have Ubuntu 16.04 on the SSD but I was going to remove it and upgrade it to 19.  Thanks for the information.